# Probability mass function of alternative Negative binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, negative-binomial

I have a random variable $X$ defined by the sum of $k$ independent geometric distributions ($Y$) with parameter $p$, which makes it a negative binomial random variable $NB(k,p)$. The probability mass function of the geometric distribution is given by
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(Y=y)=(1-p)p^{y}
\end{equation}
which is a different probability mass function than I have seen before. I can therefore not figure out what the probability mass function is of my random variable $X$. Does anyone know how I should approach this?

Comment: Is $X =\sum Y_i$?

Comment: Yes it is, I edited it in the question.

Comment: Your $Y$ seems to have support on $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ so $X$ does too.  $X$ seems to be the number of successes (each with probability $p$) by the time you see $k$ failures.  So you want $x$ successes and $k-1$ failures in any order, followed by a final failure. This has probability $\mathbb P(X=x)={x+k-1 \choose x}(1-p)^k p^x$